# How to convert glue spec like ‘\parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil’ to LuaTeX glue node

Tags: luatex

I am trying to create a glue node that I can assign to the internal parameter `tex.parfillskip`.

In Plain TeX, the glue for `\parfillskip` is assigned as `\parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil`. Dumping the values in Lua(TeX):

```
print("width: " .. tex.parfillskip.width)
print("stretch: " .. tex.parfillskip.stretch)
print("shrink: " .. tex.parfillskip.shrink)
print("stretch_order: " .. tex.parfillskip.stretch_order)
print("shrink_order: " .. tex.parfillskip.shrink_order)
```

leads to this output:

```
width: 0
stretch: 65536
shrink: 0
stretch_order: 2
shrink_order: 0
```

So my questions are:

- How does one convert a value `1fil` to the `stretch` component of the glue spec. Is it just as simple as multiplying by `65536` (as it seems from the dump)?
- How does one determine the value `stretch_order`? It seems a bit arbitrary. The value above is `2`, but the `stretch_order` value for `tex.topskip` is `0`. How does one determine what to put in that component for the glue spec.

Comment: This seems relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186117/44003

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LuaTeX introduced an additional degree of infinite glue: you can have `fi`, `fil`, `fill` and `filll`. So settings like

```
\parfillskip=0pt plus 1pt
\parfillskip=0pt plus 1fi
\parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil
\parfillskip=0pt plus 1fill
\parfillskip=0pt plus 1filll
```

will have stretch orders 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 respectively.

Indeed

```
{\directlua{tex.setglue("parfillskip",65536,65536,65536,1,1)}\showthe\parfillskip}
```

will stop with

```
> 1.0pt plus 1.0fi minus 1.0fi.
```

The units are in scaled points, so to get 1`<unit>` you need 65536 whatever `<unit>` you choose among the ones above.