# Alignment of single verses with the verse package

Tags: verse

I want to align some lines within a `verse` environment horizontally to the right, as the MWE bellow shows.

For this, neither `\hfill` nor `\flushright` work properly.

I show my best approach in the MWE:
It aligns correctly but doesn't show verse numbers.
Moreover, you have to manually enter the number of verses in that part.
In conclusion: The numbering routine doesn't work there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}

\poemlines{2} 

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
{\raggedleft
Lorem ipsum \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \\
consectetur adipiscing elit\\
\raggedright}
\addtocounter{poemline}3
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

Any other way to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use “more infinite” glue: you need `filll` to kill the `\hfill` introduced by `verse`, which is the same as `\hspace{0pt plus 1fill}` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186154/4427)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}

\newcommand{\rightverse}{\hspace{0pt plus 1filll}}

\poemlines{2}

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
\rightverse Lorem ipsum \\
\rightverse Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \\
\rightverse consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Because to John Kormylo's explanation, I can now understand why you say "plus infinite glue". Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that verse uses `\hfill` instead of `\hfil` to perform centering.  One can however use `\makebox` on each line to right align them within the given length.  Experiments indicate that `\dimexpr \linewidth+\leftmargini` is close to the length at which the line will break automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}

\newcommand{\moveit}[1]{\makebox[\dimexpr \linewidth+\leftmargini][r]{#1}}

\poemlines{2} 

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
\moveit{Lorem ipsum}\\
\moveit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,}\\
\moveit{consectetur adipiscing elit}\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent. And thanks for the explanation. I choose the egreg's solution because I preferer the sentence way, similar to \hfill, etc.